# jQuery show/hide is collapsing on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown, slideup

All the div in the middle is collapsing on page load everytime i refresh the page and the first div is going up and down one time on page load/refresh.

How do i prevent that so the page doesn't make this kind of "collapse animation" on page load and still keep the slideUp/slideDown function?

I'm using jQuery 1.11.0 with migrate 1.2.1

[Link to demo page](http://grafisk.kts.dk/elever/pola2/solsystemet/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('h3 + div').hide('slow/400/fast');
        $('h3:first').next().show('slow/400/fast');


        var $buffer = $('h3:first');

        $('#content h3').click(function() {

            var style_disp =$buffer.next().css('display');

            $(this).next().slideDown('slow/400/fast');
            if (style_disp == 'block') {
                $buffer.next().slideUp('slow/400/fast');
            }
            $buffer = $(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to be telling it to hide the div when the page is ready, have you tried simply removing that line of code?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have 2 document ready functions which is not necessary. `$(function() {` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {` so you can go ahead and remove one of those as they do the same thing.

Secondly, the options you are passing to the `hide()`/`show()` functions are incorrect. You should only be passing one speed and you are currently passing 3 different speeds.

Finally, you are hiding/showing divs on page load using `jQuery`, instead you should be hiding the divs you want to be hidden, on page load, via CSS and only use `jQuery` to toggle visibility on click.